# How to auto click a link under WebView widget in Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview-flutter

I make a flutter app and it's have a `WebView widget` to show Web Pages. in this webpage, I went to do : automatically click a specific link/Text without having access to webpage. is it possible?

Comment: Hmm, as far as I know, I don't think this is possible, it would not be very secure to let apps interact with pages loaded in a webview.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.